# android - how to remove location update IntentService automatically when app is killed

Tags: android, location, intentservice

There is a IntentService for updating the location every 10 seconds.

```
mIntentService = new Intent(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);

mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), 0,
                       mIntentService, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
            10*1000, 0, mPendingIntent);
```

the location update doesn't stop when the app is killed, it still run every 10 second. I can't  remove the location update in onDestroy() method since this service must be run even we leave the activity. How can the location update service be **cancled automatically when app is killed?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove updates for your `mLocationManager` when finished

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this); is enough, but use also checks just to be sure that your app doesn't crash. Click on the mark on the left side if this has helped you.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    removeLocationUpdates();
}

public void removeLocationUpdates(){

    if( mLocationManager != null && networkLocationListener != null ){
        if( mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ){
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(networkLocationListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't remove the location update in onDestroy() method since this service **must be run even we leave the activity**.